# How to handle these weird characters in sql before exporting to excel

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi in one of my database table in a particular column i'm getting the data something like this

```
 COLUMN 4
 =- TEST1
```

Actually `=- TEST1` is a valid data and when we put this in excel it is throwing an error due to the value. Is there anyway i can handle this data?

Hi if it is a string i tried this and it is working `select ''''||'=-test' from dual;`

but suppose i have a database column i don't know how to do.

Comment: did you try putting them in double quotes?

Comment: You can prefix single quote before exporting to excel

Comment: Actually in oracle i want to handle this. Like before we export it to excel, is there any way?

Comment: Yes in Oracle, while preparing the data prefix a single quote

Comment: What is throwing an error - Oracle or Excel? What error is it throwing?

Comment: @JeffreyKemp In excel when i'm seeing the data error is coming since `=` in excel it automaticaly takes it as a function

Comment: In that case, pre-pend the `'` character to the data when you export.

Comment: I have tried it with a string as i have mentioned above but when i use a db column im not able to know how to use it